# What is a word for what gladiators do?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I was writing a story about gladiators and wanted a word to describe what gladiators do (besides fighting), as in the phrase "X isn't just...". Arena fighting sounds too long and gladiation, which was the other option I came up with, doesn't sound like a word, even for a neologism. Preferably it should capture the fact that it took place in Ancient Rome.

[Proof this isn't a duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=gladiator)

Comment: @Robusto: I dunno. The UK popular press today often seem to be obsessed with what professional footballers get up to what they're not ***footballing***.

Comment: We would need to see the second half of your sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: [Same with American footballers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2891574/?ref_=nv_sr_1), I suppose. OK, I retract my comment.

Comment: @Robusto: Aw, *Dang!* Now my slick aside (we don't even have a proper word for what *footballers* do) is orphanned!

Comment: We have to take the bitter with the sweet.

Comment: @TimRomano I was going to write something like "X isn't just about the survivors". Could change at any time though, and if you have a better suggestion...

Comment: ***Life of a Gladiator***:

http://www.tribunesandtriumphs.org/gladiators/life-of-a-gladiator.htm

Comment: @Alpha3031: I misunderstood your question. I thought you were trying to say something like "Fighting in the arena wasn't just about *stabbing and thrusting*; a great deal of showmanship was involved". I thought you were trying to set up a rhetorical contrast.

Comment: @TimRomano That would just go right over my head :) Not too good at English. Half of what people say (in the subject, not just in the language) is nonsense to me, even though I've been speaking it since I was 7.

Comment: @Alpha3031: Odd that what I wrote is "over your head" when you used the words *gladiation* and *neologism* :)

Comment: Oh, that's just because I like suffixes. Watched the TED-Ed video on Normalization. Antiestablishmentarianism and all that. But I could be trying to set up rhetorical contrast. I just have very little idea what it means. Overreaching?

Comment: **Entertain**?.

Comment: I suppose a bricklayer could (just about) get away with saying *I'm bricklaying on a small house extension next week*, but I really don't think *I bricklaid (bricklayed?) for a big building company last year* would work. The point being *most* "occupations" don't have a verb for doing whatever is involved - and even when there is a word, things may may be quite restrictive when it comes to *how* it can be used.

Comment: @ermanen Is this not why you are here?

Comment: The obvious choice, I think, would be ***die***.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If you're looking for a word to describe what they do _besides_ fighting, then why is "arena fighting" an option? Is the "X" in the sentence where the desired word goes, or does it go in the ellipsis (i.e. the "...")?

Comment: In Italian the most correct term is *giochi gladiatori* ("gladiatori" here is the plural of the adjective "gladiatorio"), which can be translated as *gladiator games* (and thus *gladiator gaming* for their activity). Although you could refer to that also as *gladiator fighting*, the word *game* captures the essence of what they did at the time: they were actually part of the show.

Comment: BTW, the old latin term for those was *ludi gladiatorum*, literally translatable into *games of the gladiators*.

Comment: What's wrong with *fight*?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Gladiators ***gladiate***. Yes, it is a word and it is mentioned as a back-formation from gladiator in [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gladiate). It is a noun-to-verb derivation, originally from the Latin noun *gladiator* ("swordsman"), from *gladius* ("sword"). (However, it is also used in botany and means "sword-shaped").

***Gladiation*** is also in [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gladiation) and defined as a combat between gladiators. These derivations don't appear in most authoritative dictionaries but they are used as a neologism.

> We no longer go to the Colosseum to watch **gladiators gladiate** each other into oblivion. We haven't since Constantine the Great made such contests illegal in A.D. 325.
>
> <sub>*Why Michael Couldn't Hit, and Other Tales of the Neurology of Sports* By Harold L. Klawans</sub>

---

If you want a common word, you can consider ***swordfight***. (It is also related to the origin of *gladiator*: *gladius* "sword").

You didn't prefer long phrases but another option is ***gladiatorial fight*** which is the most precise term.

Comment: Dang, I was going to make up this word as a joke and add it as a comment. +1 to you, sir.

Comment: Gladiators gladiating sounds like humor to me.

Comment: @Dronz: It can be if you want.

Comment: A swordfight is not accurate. Although gladiator is derived from gladius, a short sword, various gladiators used a net/trident combination (retiarus), a lasso/dagger combination (laquearius), spears (velites and venator), dagger (arbelus), bow and arrow from horseback (saggitarius), and even a mailed boxing glove (cestus)

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Thanks for the elaboration. I knew about it, it is just a word that can be considered. It is accurate also depending on the situation.

Comment: This reminds me of when I asked my 7-year-old son, after he'd seen the first two Star Wars movie, what he thought Snow Troopers did. (At the time, he pronounced _trooper_ as /'tʃupər/, like many Americans do.) HIs reply was "They choop snow, I guess".

Comment: Well, Gladiating seems like the best we can do. Thanks to everyone for the great answers.

Comment: Thanks to this answer I realized that the flower [Gladiolus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladiolus) has the same origin as _gladiator_, since it is sword-shaped.

Answer (score 12):

*[Combat](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/combat)* seems good:

> noun
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>   1 Fighting between armed forces:
>
> verb
>
> 1.1 archaic Engage in a fight with; oppose in battle:

*The **combat** of gladiators in the colosseum satisfied the blood lust of Romans.*

From Gibbon's *[The History of the Decline and Fall of the Roman Empire](https://books.google.com/books?id=cYw8AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA74&dq=%22combat%20of%20gladiators%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JrNgVYjUA4butQWCq4GwDQ&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22combat%20of%20gladiators%22&f=false)*

> This severe reformer shews no more indulgence to a tragedy of
>   Euripides, than to a combat of gladiators

From Dunford's *[Rome: The Mini Rough Guide](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZHtejJuHlCkC&pg=PA86&dq=%22gladiatorial+combat%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3LRgVbOIFoOTsAXruoGIBA&ved=0CE4Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22gladiatorial%20combat%22&f=false)*:

> Gladiatorial combat as a Roman tradition was a direct import from the
>   Etruscans, who thought it seemly to sacrifice a few prisoners of war
>   or slaves at the funeral games of an important person.

Since *combat* is of Latin origin, it seems particularly approptiate:

> [combat](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=combat&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.)
>
> 1560s, from Middle French *combat* (16c.),
>   from *combattre*
>   (see
>   *[combat](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=combat&allowed_in_frame=0)* (v.)).
>
> 1560s, from Middle French combat (16c.),
>   from Old French *combattre*
>   (12c.),
>   from Late Latin *combattere*,
>   from Latin com- "with" (each
>   other) (see *com*-) + *battuere* "to beat, fight"
>   (see [batter](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=batter&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.)).
>
> "*strike repeatedly, beat violently and rapidly*," early 14c.,
>   from Old
>   French *batre* "to beat, strike" (11c., Modern French *battre* "to beat,
>   to strike"),
>   from Latin *battuere* "to beat, strike," an old word in
>   Latin, but almost certainly borrowed from Gaulish,
>   from PIE root
>   * *bhau*- "to strike"
>   (cognates: Welsh bathu "beat;" Old English beadu "battle," beatan "to beat," bytl "hammer, mallet").

Wikipedia uses the word *[combat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladiator#Combat)* in reference to the activity of gladiators:

> In the earliest *munera*, death was considered the proper outcome of
>   ***combat***. [**Emphasis** added]

Comment: I suppose one might suggest "duelling". On the one hand, Roman gladiatorial fights were one-on-one, not melees; on the other, you'd need context making it clear that we aren't talking "ten paces turn and fire" or Heidelberg sabre scars. I reckon the metaphorical usage of duelling is pretty standard, though.

Comment: Suggest using as 'gladiatorial combat' or 'mortal combat'

Comment: @DavidPugh Duelling can definitely be with swords. However Roman gladiators also did group combats.

Comment: @Dronz: mea culpa, I was thinking about the days when they had twofers of sword versus net. In what period did they do group combats? Still not melees like the medieval tournaments (real, not Ivanhoe)?

Comment: @DavidPugh I'd have to search to see if I can find a first group combat date, but I think it was early or even from the start. They were different from medieval tourneys in that those were mostly non-lethal sport for knights, as opposed to public entertainment mostly by a gladiator class, captives and slaves, and in that they were arranged matches. While some high-status Romans chose to enter the arena (even some emperors!), they tended to do so in matches with very good odds. There were also recreations of histoic and mythic battles in the arena, even naval battle...

Comment: @Ah yes, I'd forgotten the recreated naval battles. One of the Julio-Claudians, wasn't that? But this is getting a bit far from the OP. I'm glad for the "mostly", you could get seriously dead in a 12th-century tournament, which why the church banned them. They were realistic war games, not jousts.

Answer (score 4):

What about "compete" or "perform"?

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). Those are good suggestions, but how about some references to corroborate them? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Fight
verb
1.  take part in a violent struggle involving the exchange of physical blows or the use of weapons.

Comment: Perfectly straight forward and correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best single-word summary that comes to mind of what gladiators do would be

> **slaughter**
>   2. the savage killing of a person

<sup>[TFD Online](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slaughter)</sup>

Comment: Good answer, but not quite what I was looking for. Thanks anyway. (and I'll upvote when I can)

Comment: Slaughter implies a one-sided act. If a gladiator slaughters someone, it wasn't much of a fight.

Comment: @Dronz: The end result is the same. It's the savagery that counts.

Answer (score 0):

**arena combat** (a noun phrase, not a single word, sorry)

Comment: No problem, I handed in my assignment already anyway. :)

Comment: @Alpha3031 *"Are you not entertained?"*

Comment: If you wanted to turn this into a verb, you could say something like 'perform arena combat'.

Comment: @dwjohnston: sure, but it's less clunky to just say *"Being a gladiator isn't just arena combat"*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the goal was to kill the other contestants ("In the earliest munera, death was considered the proper outcome of combat." - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladiator#Combat)), the term *deathmatch*, common in video gaming, seems to fit:

> Normally the goal of a deathmatch [or Free-For-All] game is to kill ... as many other players as possible until a certain condition or limit is reached - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathmatch)

(admittedly using a term coined in the 1990s to describe an activity popular in the 0000s would be an anachronism, but then so is using any English)